# Gremlin: Performing Text Search in AWS Neptune

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Using Gremlin how can I perform Text search like,

```
- Name starts with "A"
- Name ends with "B"
- Name contains "t"
- etc.
```

I know NEO4J and Janus have some custom code for such a thing.

I figured out Neptune does not support Regex. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=854392

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the only option at this point is support for `startsWith()` like functionality as in:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has('name',between('m','n'))
==>v[1]
```

The rest is just not possible with Neptune at this time - more discussion on this topic is present on this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51133414/1831717).

**UPDATE:** As of TinkerPop 3.6.0, Gremlin now has a `TextP.regex` predicate that can help with these sorts of searches:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', TextP.regex('m.*o')).elementMap()
==>[id:1,label:person,name:marko,age:29]
```

You may read more about it in the [Upgrade Documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_textp_regex).

Comment: between is case sensitive, so is there a way to search it as case-insensitive? (instead of saving name in the graph db as lower case)